# inconsistent results when finding duplicates using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset and want to remove the duplicate records.

When i run `len(df[df.duplicated()])` i get 1633 as output.

when i run the below to get the list of duplicate records i get a different output of 3230 rows

```
dupdf1 = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values(["customer_id","product_id"])
```

when i run the below to get the list of duplicate records using subset i get a different output of 3298 rows

```
dupdf2 = df[df.duplicated(subset=["customer_id","product_id","price"],keep=False)].sort_values(["customer_id","product_id"])
```

There are duplicates in the dataset but also cases where only the price column value is different which should not be excluded.

Example of duplicate record
[image]

Example of a record where price field has different values.
[image]

How can i remove duplicates where all the the field values are duplicate?

Comment: When you use subset, you are only removing rows where the values in the subset of columns are duplicates. Simply input for `subset` all column values except `price` and you should get what you want.

Comment: But even price can be duplicate as per the screenshot above. Please check customer_id = 15822. The price is also  duplicate

Comment: If you want to remove all fields that are duplicated (price included), then use `df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]`. If you to remove all fields that are duplicated EXCEPT price, then use `df[df.duplicated(subset=[list_of_all_other_columns_except_price], keep=False)]`

Comment: Sure, but when i run dupdf1 = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values(["customer_id","product_id"]) - i get the list of duplicates. How can i get a list excluding the duplicates but should have records where all fields are duplicates except price

Comment: use `.drop_duplicates` instead - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: sorry what im trying to achieve is a list of unique duplicate records.  df[df.duplicated(keep=False)] has more records as the index number is also included in the list hence we see more records. My concern was why .drop_duplicates outputs 1633 and the when the duplicate list is generator it contains more records 3230.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237553/discussion-between-jag99-and-kelvt).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured why there was inconsistency when exporting the duplicate list. I was adding the keep=False option which exports all the duplicate records as shown below.

1. `duplicates=df[df.duplicated()]` : This will only export on of the duplicate values
2. `dupdf = df[df.duplicated(keep= False)]` : This will export all the duplicate values

[image]